# Getting Only direct element in beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```html
<body>
  <p class="title">
    <b>
      The Dormouse's story
    </b>
  </p>
  <p class="story">
    ....
    <b>
      A tale
    </b>
  </p>  
</body>
```

I need to get all direct children of tag `<body>`, but not the grand children. So in this case, it should only output `<p class="title">` and `<p class="story">`.

The closest method I found outputs both tags and all of their children. How can I do it right?

Comment: Do you just want to output the different classes: 'title' and 'story'?

Comment: Same question: what do you actually want to do with it? :)

Comment: no, i wanted to get entire line of <p class="title"> and <p class="story"> . i need a way to do that without knowing what tag under the body is .

Comment: See my answer below, it provides both options.

Comment: i need to do that without knowing what tag is under the body so i cant do something like targeting p tag or anyhing

Comment: @fajarakurniawan What have you tried? Isn't it enough to find the body and iterate over its children? Show your code and explain how it fails.

Comment: see my answer: child= soup.find_next(lambda x: re.search('<',str(x))) to find without knowing the tag

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can use `find_all(recursive=False)` to get all the children tags. [`recursive=False`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument) gets you the direct children of the tag. Then, the only thing I've done is the formatting the data into strings.

I've added some more attributes to the tags to show it works for all cases.

```
html = '''
<body>
  <p class="title" id="title">
    <b>
      The Dormouse's story
    </b>
  </p>
  <p class="story stories">
    ....
    <b>
      A tale
    </b>
  </p>  
</body>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.body.find_all(recursive=False):
    attributes = ' '.join('{}="{}"'.format(
        key, 
        ' '.join(value) if isinstance(value, list) else value
    ) for key, value in tag.attrs.items())

    tag_string = '<{} {}>'.format(tag.name, attributes)
    print(tag_string)
```

Output:

```
<p class="title" id="title">
<p class="story stories">
```

The reason I've used `' '.join(value) if isinstance(value, list) else value` instead of directly using `value` is that the attributes of `class` are available in a list.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to extract the `class` tags, then this will do it:

```
s = '''<body>
    <p class="title">
        <b>
        The Dormouse's story
        </b>    
    <p class="story">
        ....
            <b>
        A tale
            </b>
    </p>    
</body>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(i.get('class'))
```

Output:

```
['title']
['story']
```

Or you can use regex to get the whole tag returned:

```
import re

print(re.findall(r'(?:<p).*?(?:>)', str(soup)))
```

Output:

```
['<p class="title">', '<p class="story">']
```

Answer (score 0):

i got my messy and ugly answer for my problem right now which kinda like this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(a,'html5lib')
list = []
for child in soup.body.children:
list.append(child)

text = str(list[1])
x, y, z = text.partition('>')
a = x+y
print (a)

text = str(list[2])
x2, y2, z2 = text.partition('>')
a2 = x2+y2
print (a2)
```

kinda work with my problem right now, which will only show

```
<p class="title">
```

and`<p class="story">`

if anyone have better or neater solution is appreciated
thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

HTML='''<body>...'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML,'lxml').body
child= soup.find_next(lambda x: re.search('<',str(x)))
print(child)
print(child.find_next_sibling(lambda x: re.search('<',str(x))))
```

soup.find_next() finds the next element (and next element only), because you want to find the next tags without knowing the tag (search for "<", if returns true, grabs that element). soup.find_next_sibling() will find the next sibling of the tag(i.e. the next lateral tag, in this case class="story"

Comment: Answers with just code and no text get flagged as low quality, why no try explaining your answer a bit to help avoid it getting deleted.